# How to deeplink in Nextjs

Tags: next.js, deep-linking

I am currently using window.assign(bundlename://linkname) to deeplink a user into the app if it’s installed on their device but I keep getting Safari cannot open page because the address is invalid

I also tried to use  window.location.assign = bundlename://linkname but that does not work either

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, Please share a completely reproducible example - in your case did you add changes  to your iOS app in the `.plist` assigning a url scheme and are you listening to those events? Where exactly are you setting window.assign? Does a regular `a` link produce the same resul?

Comment: @Ramakay a regular a tag produces the same result. I am setting my window.assign to the uri scheme for the app. Like so 
                 <button
                    className="Button"
                    onClick={() => {
                      window.location.assign(url);
                    }}
                  >
                    Open
                  </button>

Comment: Could you confirm that the associated app changes were done per platform - iOS plist etc.

Comment: I see this error on click of open app - It looks like the bundle URL is actually not linked.
```
[Error] Unhandled Promise Rejection: Error: The provided `href` (/links/community/user/[username]) value is missing query values (username) to be interpolated properly. Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/href-interpolation-faile...
 dispatchException (main-08708831c35d70c3a4f6.js:1:61050)
 (anonymous function) (main-08708831c35d70c3a4f6.js:1:57278)
 t (main-08708831c35d70c3a4f6.js:1:479)
 u (main-08708831c35d70c3a4f6.js:1:691)
 promiseReactionJob
``` Please post your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the detailed comments - I am able to open with `document.location`

See this sandbox, replace with an app scheme if you do not have Doordash installed - https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-lewin-ydbp5?file=/pages/index.js

Comment: Thank you sir this works!!

Comment: Awesome, if this Or another answer helped please mark it as the accepted answer